# Adding custom setting to PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android

I have a `PreferenceFragment` and I need to put custom preferences in it. Now the problems are not the custom preferences themselves, I already extended some `DialogPreference`s creating my own preferences and I already dealt with saving/restoring data; the problem is how do I add these custom preferences to my `PreferenceFragment`? I can't declare them in XML (can I?), and I can't find any method to dynamically add them to my `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself, but for an xml based approach, maybe you can do this:

```
<com.mypackage.MyPreference
        android:defaultValue="value"
        android:key="key"
        android:title="Title"/>
```

Then use `addPreferencesFromResource()` as usual.